# Ruby on Rails, I try to create a form using the application, but when I get to the show page..everything is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, show, react-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am having an issue when I am about to submit my form. Everything when well when I was about to create the form(as shown in 1st picture), but as soon as I get to the show path I show nothing of what I input to the form (as shown on 2nd picture).Can somebody eluded where I was wrong?
[image]

[image]
in my todos_controller.rb :

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
def index
    @todos= Todo.all
end

def new
end

def show
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @todo= Todo.new(todo_params)

    @todo.save
    redirect_to @todo
end

private
    def todo_params
        params.require(:todo).permit(:task, :description)
    end
end
```

In my show.html.erb:

```
<p>
    <strong>Task:</strong>
    <%= @todo.task %>
    </p>

<p>
     <strong>Description:</strong>
     <%= @todo.description %>
     </p>
```

in my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'welcome/index'

resources :todos

root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your form page(todo#new) you need to have an object for those attributes(:task, :description) to be saved to in the database.